# SQL - Select from table, if user_id is 0 select from different table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently struggling with a SQL query, I have 2 tables, `clients` and `clientbook`.

---

### The context

`clientbook` is the table where **there will always be a client entry**:

```
id | firstname | lastname | user_id | saloon_id
-----------------------------------------------
1    lorem       ipsum      5         10
2    jack        inthebox   0         10
```

`clients` may or may not have an entry, based on if the client was logged in or not at the time of reservation. If `clientbook.user_id` is 0, the client won't be in `clients` table. `clients` looks like this:

```
user_id | firstname | lastname
------------------------------
5         lorem       ipsum
```

---

#### The question

I want to make the following query:

If `clientbook.user_id` is not `0`, then query `clients` and select the `clients.firstname` and `clients.lastname` from there.

If `clientbook.user_id` is `0`, select the `clientbook.firstname` and `clientbook.lastname`.

---

### What I currently have

I have this query:

```
    SELECT 
        c.firstname,
        c.lastname
    FROM
        clients AS c
    INNER JOIN
        clientbook AS cb
    ON
        c.id = cb.user_id
    WHERE
        c.firstname LIKE CONCAT("%", 'lorem', "%")
    AND
        cb.saloon_id = 10
```

However, this will only select from `clients` if there is a row present. If no row exists, it will not select from `clientbook`.

How can I make this query?

Comment: Side note: Maybe you shouldn't be searching the `clients` table for names when this is available in `clientbook`.  The current approach seems to unnecessarily complicate that logic.  Notice that you can't directly use the result of the selected `COALESCE` in the corresponding `WHERE` clause, etc.  It's a bit inconvenient.  Are the names in these two tables different or just copies of each other?  If copies, consider just removing the name from `clients`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If clientbook.user_id is not 0, then query clients and select the clients.firstname and clients.lastname from there.
>
> If clientbook.user_id is 0, select the clientbook.firstname and clientbook.lastname.

Based on this description, you want a `left join`

```
select coalesce(c.firstname, cb.firstname) as firstname,
       coalesce(c.lastname, cb.lastname) as lastname
from clientbook cb left join
     clients c
     on cb.user_id = c.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 create table clientbook(id int, firstname varchar(50), lastname varchar(50), user_id int, saloon_id int);
 insert into clientbook values(1,    'lorem',  'ipsum',      5,         10);
 insert into clientbook values(2,    'jack',   'inthebox',   0,         10);
 
 create table clients (user_id int, firstname varchar(50), lastname varchar(50));
 insert into clients values(5,         'lorem','ipsum'   );
```

Query:

```
   SELECT 
         (case when cb.user_id=0 then cb.firstname else c.firstname end)firstname,
         (case when cb.user_id=0 then cb.lastname else c.lastname end)lastname
     FROM
         clientbook AS cb
     Left JOIN
         clients AS c
     ON
         c.user_id = cb.user_id
    
     AND
         cb.saloon_id = 10
```

Ouput:

| firstname | lastname |
| --- | --- |
| lorem | ipsum |
| jack | inthebox |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5f8ad4be06b6dfeb9f922ad542568be9)*

Answer (score 1):

I understood you want to bring the names from clientbooks table if you do have the matching row on client table. To do that you can combine a CASE and a Left join. Although you could also creat a sub-select or Union all query to bring them altogether. The detail is you should join them by “user_id” column.

`SELECT ( CASE  WHEN cb.user_id = 0 THEN cb.firstname ELSE c.firstname END ) AS firstname ,( CASE  WHEN cb.user_id = 0 THEN cb.lastname ELSE c.lastname END ) AS lastname FROM clientbook AS cb LEFT JOIN clients AS c ON c.user_id = cb.user_id WHERE c.firstname LIKE CONCAT ( "%" ,'lorem' ,"%" ) AND cb.saloon_id = 10`